# Realm for Desktop apps

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, realm

Is there a way to use Realm from [realm.io](https://realm.io/) for a desktop (WinForms/WPF) appliaction?

I have tried the following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Realm realm;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.realm = Realm.GetInstance();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        realm.Write(() =>
        {
            var jim = realm.CreateObject<Person>();
            var myDog = realm.CreateObject<Dog>();

            myDog.Name = "Fido";
            myDog.Owner = jim;
        });
    }
}

public class Dog : RealmObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Person Owner { get; set; }
}

public class Person : RealmObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Dog> Dogs { get; }
}
```

but when executing it, VS shows me a `PlatformNotSupportedException`

Comment: Nope: https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/509#issuecomment-250051237 and https://github.com/realm/realm-core/issues/2036 and https://github.com/realm/realm-core/issues/2059

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, as @EpicPandaForce points out, we don't yet support any desktop environments. Keep an eye on those github issues though.